# cannot read property 'src' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, undefined, typeerror

I get the error from the title in the follow JS:

```
$('.videoMedia .youtubeLink').each(function(i) {
 // Defining the iframe for each iteration
 var iframe = $(this).parents('li').find('.portfolio_det iframe');

 // Cutting the src from the iframe in pieces
 var begin = 'http://www.youtube.com/embed/'.length;
 var end = iframe[0].src.length-'?fs=1&feature=oembed'.length;
```

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'src' of undefined**

```
 // Substracting the pieces
 var videolink = iframe[0].src.substring(begin,end);

 // Replacing the link with the leftovers
 $(this).attr('href', 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' + videolink); 

     // Removing the iframe
 $(iframe).remove();
});
```

Any ideas why it thinks its undefined? Since iframe is defined on top of the function. Suggestions are welcome :)

**Edit**

Example of this script in "action" (not sure to call it like this, since there aint any action going on) is seen on: http://sqps.nl/bdare/?page_id=279

Currently it only works for the last element on the right/bottom (with the bdare / youtube img)

**Edit 2**

Strange thing is, it used to work before (on localhost using xampp)

**Edit 3 - problem fixxed**

Hereby I would like to thank all of you who joined this discussion :) 
I have found the solution.. Nothing was wrong with my code at all :)
The input from the wordpress post provoked the script from running properly, changing the content of the posts fixxed the problem :)

Cheers :)

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(iframe)` to ensure it's getting the element? I suspect it's because you're using the `[0]` and it probably isn't returning an array/nodeList.

Comment: Can you also post your HTML so we can see it's structure, and see how you need to traverse it. Also, if you run this: `alert(iframe.length)` if you see `0`, it means your iframe is not being found.

Comment: Your selector doesn't select any iframe. Hence `iframe[0]` is `undefined`, and `undefined.src` does not exist. Can you show your HTML code?

Comment: I've just checked the HTML of your site, the problem is the `.find('.portfolio_det iframe')` selector - the `.portfolio_det` element does not contain an iframe.

Comment: .portfolio_det only doesnt contain an iframe in the first iteration of the li.videoMedia. The other 2 does contain an .portfolio_det.
So still kinda strange to me

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
var iframe = $(this).parents('li').find('.portfolio_det iframe');
```

is not finding any elements.  This means that `iframe[0]` is undefined instead of an object, so any attempt at property access will result in the error you're getting.

Verify your markup is correct.

Comment: Maybe i'm wrong but if `iframe[0]` is still a jQuery object, `src` is undefined even if the markup is correct

Comment: @Nicola: `iframe[0]` won't be a jQuery object.  `iframe` is a jQuery object, `[0]` is an attempt at accessing a DOM element from that jQuery object.

Comment: Ok, i tought you nedded `get(0)` to access the DOM element

Answer (score -1):

Try instead

```
var end = iframe.get(0).src.length-'?fs=1&feature=oembed'.length;
```

`iframe` is a reference to a jQuery object so `iframe[0]` it is. That's why you got an error: `src` is not a valid property of jQuery object

Comment: `.get(0)` and `[0]` are synonymous, numeric properties of jQuery objects are usually DOM objects, never jQuery objects.